# Is there a way to reference gulpfile.js and package.json (from remote location)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, npm, gulp

We have multiple separate ui modules (separate git projects). We are using npm to download dev dependencies for gulp and then gulp precompiles sass, uglify js, build template cash, runs local lint and tests. This means every module have almost identical package.json and gulpfile.js. Is there a way to re-use those, referencing them and not copy them in every project? Or maybe inheriting settings and configuration from a parent like maven does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely there is.

On the project I'm working now we have quite the same situation: frontend modules are separated into different repositories and have very similar sets of gulp tasks. So, we've moved those tasks to a `gulp-common` repo and installed it as a dev dependency via npm:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp-common": "git+ssh://our-repo-url/gulp-common.git"
}
```

Then, in order to load these gulp tasks, we've modified the `gulpfile.js` so now it looks like this:

```
require('require-dir')('build/tasks'); // load specific tasks from the usual place
require('require-dir')('node_modules/gulp-common/build/tasks'); // load common tasks
```

Meanwhile, in the gulp-common we have a `./build` directory with tasks  and an `index.js` file:

```
module.exports = require('require-dir')('./build');
```

Cheers!